# What does the verb bound mean in this sentence of Thoreau's?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, verbs

In [A Plea for Captain John Brown](https://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/205), Thoreau writes:

> When he was here, some years ago, he showed to a few a little manuscript book,—his “orderly book” I think he called it,—containing the names of his company in Kansas, and the rules by which they **[bound](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bound#Verb_3)** themselves; and he stated that several of them had already sealed the contract with their blood.

[Having done research](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bound#Verb_3), methinks *bound* neither means *to
surround a territory or other geographical entity; to form the boundary of* nor *to leap* in this sentence.

What does the verb *bound* mean in this sentence?

Comment: Have you looked it up in a dictionary? The fitting definition seems pretty clear. EL&U typically expects a minimum of research and an explanation of how this research failed to answer the question.

Comment: @DW256 I modified my question in response to your worthy comment.

Comment: You do know it's the past tense of [bind](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bind#English)?

Comment: The last sense given in [CD](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/bind). Sense 1c (with near-exact example) in [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bind).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Background :**

Word Web says [Bind](https://www.wordwebonline.com/search.pl?w=bind) means :

> Create social or emotional ties

> Bind by an obligation; cause to be indebted
>
> > "He's bound by a contract";

Word Web says [Bound](https://www.wordwebonline.com/search.pl?w=bound) means :

> Place limits on

> Bound by an oath
>
> > "a bound official"

Bound is the Past tense of Bind.

**What the means in the Sentence ?**
" ... a little manuscript book ... containing ... the rules by which they **bound** themselves ... "

It means that these rules are binding them ( compelling them to ) to certain actions & prohibiting them ( compelling them away from ) from certain other actions.

No body is forcing them , they have made the rules themselves.